# "The specified table does not exist" - for the administrator it does! Vista only issue

Tags: windows-vista, sql-server-ce

I've got a weird bug occurring in a compact database on a Vista deployment machine. Basically the sdf file seem to be schizophrenic.

The client application get the entitled error when running as a user but not when I use run as administrator. I don't see this problem on my XP development machine.

I installed management studio onto the deployment machine and opened two versions of the application, one as user and one as administrator. When I query:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

I see 21 tables on the one and 26 on the other, and the administrator is seeing less tables. It turns out that the user version, with 26 rows, is a previous incarnation of this database.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to revolve around a cached version of the database being created during installation to the deployment machine.

## edit

vista virtual file store is to blame. We altered the application to use the All User Profile area for dumping the data in.